# create new column for result depending on blank columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

```
I have table as below, in row number 2("AAPOP"), 6("AB"), 9("QDA98"), I don't have any value in "remarks" and "details" column


Particulars          Remark    Details         AMT  
AAPOP               
QP                       av      daf            7   
WP                       ad      dae            8   
ST                       df      dds            9   
AB              
RR                      dasd      df            6   
RA                       dsf      we            8   
QDA98               
DRS                      sd       df            5   
DRW                      sd       dsa           3   
UTS                     dad       fds           6   

I want to create "log" column and paste value for those column who is not contain any value in column 'remarks' and 'details', in below example it is "AAPOP, "AB", "QDA98"



Particulars         Remark    Details   log      AMT
AAPOP                                  AAPOP    
QP                     av       daf               7
WP                     ad       dae               8
ST                     df       dds               9
AB                                       AB 
RR                    dasd       df               6
RA                     dsf       we               8
QDA98                                   QDA98   
DRS                     sd       df               5
DRW                     sd      dsa               3
UTS                    dad      fds               6
```

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Have you read the Pandas docs? This seems like an extremely basic question. Also, can’t you use NaN to denote missing/empty values, instead of an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work, although I’m not 100% certain. If it doesn’t, the solution should be very similar. I will test it tomorrow and update my post.

```py
df['log'] = ''
df.loc[(df['Remark'] == '') & (df['Details'] == ''), 'log'] = df['Particulars']
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, try this

```
df['log']= np.where((df.Remark.isnull()) & (df.Remark.isnull()),df.Particulars,'')
df
```

**Input**

```
Particulars     Remark  Details     AMT
0   AAPOP   None    None    NaN
1   QP  av  daf     7.0
2   WP  ad  dae     8.0
3   ST  df  dds     9.0
4   AB  None    None    NaN
5   RR  dasd    df  6.0
6   RA  dsf     we  8.0
7   QDA98   None    None    NaN
8   DRS     sd  df  5.0
9   DRW     sd  dsa     3.0
10  UTS     dad     fds     6.0
```

**Output**

```
Particulars     Remark  Details     AMT     log
0   AAPOP   None    None    NaN     AAPOP
1   QP  av  daf     7.0     
2   WP  ad  dae     8.0     
3   ST  df  dds     9.0     
4   AB  None    None    NaN     AB
5   RR  dasd    df  6.0     
6   RA  dsf     we  8.0     
7   QDA98   None    None    NaN     QDA98
8   DRS     sd  df  5.0     
9   DRW     sd  dsa     3.0     
10  UTS     dad     fds     6.0
```

Comment: `df.Remark.isnull() & df.Remark.isnull()` ? I strongly suggest not using that style of column indexing. I also don’t see why you would use `numpy.where` instead of an idiomatic Pandas solution.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try this:

```
def log_func(row):
    # return the value in Particulars column if these columns are empty
    if not any([row['Remark'], row['Details'], row['AMT']])
        return row['Particulars']
    else 
        return ''

d['log'] = d.apply(log_func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is `apply()` really necessary for this?